# Cannot connect to realtime database in editor with service account

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Using the Unity Firebase SDK 4.1.0 I can connect to the realtime database in the Unity Editor if I disable authentication e.g.

```realtime
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

In the client:

```c#
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xxx.firebaseio.com");
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
DatabaseReference reference = database.GetReference("key");
etc.
```

This works fine until I try to use a service account (so that I can enable authentication although I get the same result with authentication disabled when using a service account). The service account has the Project Editor role in IAM settings.

Updated client:

```c#
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://xxx.firebaseio.com");
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12FileName("p12filename.p12");
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorServiceAccountEmail("username@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorP12Password("notasecret");
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
DatabaseReference reference = database.GetReference("key");
etc.
```

There are no errors loading the file, however when getting the database the plugin seems to get stuck in an authentication loop and I see the following repeated in the console every few seconds (with verbose logging enabled):

```
Sending OAuth request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Requesting https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Waiting for result of https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
About to send message to POST -> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
CONTENT-TYPE:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
body size:793
OAuth request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token completed with code 200
OAuth request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token completed with msg {
  "access_token" : "yyy",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
```

I think this is a bug but want to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.